# How to replace bottom of a gable wall

Tags: carpentry, gable

I have a small gable wall that has my front door and a window. The roof comes out from the main portion of the house.

The bottom of the gable wall is in really bad shape. They used a 2x4 as the sill plate and stacked bricks every foot or so to support it. So it's very saggy and split in some spots.

How can I support the top half of the gable wall so I can replace the bottom? Usually I'd build a temporary wall but since it's a gable wall there are no joists to support.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'm thinking you could do a variation on [flying buttresses.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flying_buttress) It's a design that has withstood the test of time.

Build a few of these, and nail them to the studs. If you can put some on both sides of the wall, even better. If you can attach the top end to the roof, that wouldn't hurt either.

(Existing wall is brown; temporary support is green.)

[image: buttress]